# Can I run my Azure Static Web App and ASP.NET web API locally?

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

In Azure, I have a Static Web App and an ASP.NET web API (running in App Service).

Following this guide on Microsoft learn https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/local-development, I know it's possible to run a static web app and an azure functions API locally, but I can't find anything about a different kind of API.

When I run the CLI command " swa start dist/MyApp.front-end --api-location 'C:\GIT\MyApp.Backend'" I get the error:

```
[api] Unable to find project root. Expecting to find one of host.json, local.settings.json in project root.
```

This makes sense... because my project has appsettings.development.json instead of the local.settings.json, but I was hoping it was smart enough to use the other files.

Does anyone have any experience with running a static web app and asp.net api locally with the static web app CLI?

Comment: could you check this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/add-api?tabs=vanilla-javascript) if it helps

Comment: This only refers to azure functions sadly